# jquery tabs nav disappears

Tags: jquery, navigation

I am working on some simple jquery navigation tabs.

the animation works but when you click one of the buttons that navigation disappears.

I want the nav to stay and only show the content.

```
$(".livefeed-tabs-comment a").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    idTab = $(this).attr("href");
    $(".livefeed-tabs-comment .active").removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $(idTab).siblings().stop().fadeOut(100, function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(idTab).fadeIn(100);
        }, 100)
    })
})
```

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/CXMDa/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/CXMDa/6/)**

Try this

```
 $(".livefeed-tabs-comment a").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    idTab = $(this).attr("href");
    $(".livefeed-tabs-comment .active").removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $(idTab).siblings('div').stop().fadeOut(100, function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(idTab).fadeIn(100);
        }, 100)
    })
})
```

Hope this helps,Thank you

Comment: Hey for some reason you viewed old code .. can you please look at this demo jsfiddle.net/CXMDa/5    ???

Comment: The nav is stays but the animation from tab to tab doesn't work?

Comment: @PaulO'Brien its because of your css, padding  attribute, the padding attribute clears the area around it ,you are setting the same for each anchore element

Answer (score 0):

Two issues here:

```
idTab = $(this).attr("href");
```

You're setting the variable `idTab` to a **`string`**, namely the destination of whichever `<a>` tag is clicked. But this isn't used anywhere else in the script.

Later, you call

```
$(idTab).siblings().stop().fadeOut(100, function() { ...
```

where `idTab` is still set to a URL (it's not an element or a jQuery object).

So, you should set a variable to the `$(this)` object to use it later in your `setTimeout`. **Also,** your selector for the `click` event is `".livefeed-tabs-comment a"`. Since you're targeting the `<a>` tags, and each of those enclosed in an `<li>`, that means **they don't have any siblings** for use with `.siblings()`.

The following code should fix things up:

```
$(".livefeed-tabs-comment li").click(function(e){
    var $self = $(this),
        idTab = $self.attr("href");
    e.preventDefault();
    $self.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active').stop().fadeOut(100, function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            $self.fadeIn(100);
        }, 100)
    })
});
```

### [View the demo here.](http://jsfiddle.net/CXMDa/3/)

Comment: Hi Jacob, for some reason you viewed old code .. can you please look at this demo http://jsfiddle.net/CXMDa/5/